# How to avoid the overwriting without using .push() in Firebase? Using the autoincrement to generate ID to replace .push()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to generate the ID(autoincrement) to replace the unique ID. Could somebody help me to solve this problem? Thank you!

```
public void SignUp(){

    int UserCount = 1;
    String identifier ="User" + UserCount;
    Firebase userRef = firebaseRef.child("Users");
    EditText nameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    String name = nameInput.getText().toString();

    EditText passInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordTxt);
    String password = passInput.getText().toString();

    EditText addrInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);
    String address = addrInput.getText().toString();
    if (!name.equals("")){
        Map<String, String> infor= new HashMap<String, String>();
        caloocan.put("Usersname", name);
        caloocan.put("Userspassword", password);
        caloocan.put("Usersaddress", address);

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> users = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        users.put(identifier,infor);

        userRef.setValue(users);
        UserCount++;
    }
}
```

[Unique ID which is generated by Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnLEN.jpg)

[Generate the ID by using auto-increment just like I'm using in SQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckFLr.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid using `push()` method, then you need to retrieve all users from your database before setting the value.

Here's how to do that

```
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + 1;
        String identifier = "User" + count;

        // save the new user
        userRef.setValue( ... );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: you should explain what's the exact problem you are having in your question so others don't have to guess :)

Comment: I want to generate ID based on auto-increment method means that the ID will be started from 0. If the second users try to sign up, the ID will plus 1 and the ID will become 1 instead of using the unique ID which is generated by Firebase. You can refer this picture then you can know what I'm saying already. :D

Comment: could you help me to find the solution? I have showed in the picture that I said the ID which is using auto-increment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
final DatabaseReference firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
final DatabaseReference mCounterRef = firebaseRef.child("counter");
// listen for single change
mCounterRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // getValue() returns Long
        long count = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Users").getValue();

        System.out.println("count before setValue()=" + count);

        mCounterRef.child("count").setValue(++count);  // <= Change to ++count

        System.out.println("count after setValue()=" + count);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // throw an error if setValue() is rejected
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

If the app crashed while running then you should add this part:

```
mCounterRef.child("users").setValue(++count, new 
    DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,
                           DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError != null) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```