# Firebase database change auto gererated key though android program

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: c]

i want to change that auto generated key by ascending numbers. while adding data through android code.
can someone help me?
Thank you...

Comment: You can't change the way the SDK generates these strings.  Why do you need to do so?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519021/how-to-create-auto-incremented-key-in-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59314515, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28915836, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545767, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54379781 and probably more